# Writing Efficient Queries in SAS Using Proc sql with Teradata

Tags: sql, sas, teradata

EDIT:  Here is a more complete set of code that shows exactly what's going on per the answer below.

```
libname output '/data/files/jeff'
%let DateStart = '01Jan2013'd;
%let DateEnd = '01Jun2013'd;
proc sql;
CREATE TABLE output.id AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT id
  FROM mydb.sale_volume AS sv
  WHERE sv.category IN ('a', 'b', 'c') AND
    sv.trans_date BETWEEN &DateStart AND &DateEnd
)
CREATE TABLE output.sums AS (
  SELECT id, SUM(sales)
  FROM mydb.sale_volue AS sv
  INNER JOIN output.id AS ids
    ON ids.id = sv.id
  WHERE sv.trans_date BETWEEN &DateStart AND &DateEnd
  GROUP BY id
)
run;
```

The goal is to simply query the table for some id's based on category membership.  Then I sum these members' activity across all categories.

The above approach is far slower than:

1. Running the first query to get the subset
2. Running a second query the sums every ID
3. Running a third query that inner joins the two result sets.

If I'm understanding correctly, it may be more efficient to make sure that all of my code is completely passed through rather than cross-loading.

---

After posting a question yesterday, a member suggested I might benefit from asking a separate question on performance that was more specific to my situation.

I'm using SAS Enterprise Guide to write some programs/data queries.  I don't have permissions to modify the underlying data, which is stored in 'Teradata'.

My basic problem is writing efficient SQL queries in this environment.  For example, I query a large table (with tens of millions of records) for a small subset of ID's.  Then, I use this subset to query the larger table again:

```
proc sql;
CREATE TABLE subset AS (
  SELECT
    id
  FROM
    bigTable
  WHERE
    someValue = x AND
    date BETWEEN a AND b

)
```

This works in a matter of seconds and returns 90k ID's.  Next, I want to query this set of ID's against the big table, and problems ensue.  I'm wanting to sum values over time for the ID's:

```
proc sql;
CREATE TABLE subset_data AS (
  SELECT
    bigTable.id,
    SUM(bigTable.value) AS total
  FROM
    bigTable
  INNER JOIN subset
    ON subset.id = bigTable.id
  WHERE
    bigTable.date BETWEEN a AND b
  GROUP BY
    bigTable.id
)
```

For whatever reason, this takes a really long time.  The difference is that the first query flags 'someValue'.  The second looks at all activity, regardless of what's in 'someValue'.  For example, I could flag every customer who orders a pizza.  Then I would look at every purchase for all customers who ordered pizza.

I'm not overly familiar with SAS so I'm looking for any advice on how to do this more efficiently or speed things up.  I'm open to any thoughts or suggestions and please let me know if I can offer more detail.  I guess I'm just surprised the second query takes so  long to process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most critical thing to understand when using SAS to access data in Teradata (or any other external database for that matter) is that the SAS software prepares SQL and submits it to the database.  The idea is to try and relieve you (the user) from all the database specific details.  SAS does this using a concept called "implict pass-through", which just means that SAS does the translation from SAS code into DBMS code.  Among the many things that occur is data type conversion:  SAS only has two (and only two) data types, numeric and character.

SAS deals with translating things for you but it can be confusing.  For example, I've seen "lazy" database tables defined with VARCHAR(400) columns having values that never exceed some smaller length (like column for a person's name).  In the data base this isn't much of a problem, but since SAS does not have a VARCHAR data type, it creates a variable 400 characters wide for each row.  Even with data set compression, this can really make the resulting SAS dataset unnecessarily large.

The alternative way is to use "explicit pass-through", where you write native queries using the actual syntax of the DBMS in question.  These queries execute entirely on the DBMS and return results back to SAS (which still does the data type conversion for you.  For example, here is a "pass-through" query that performs a join to two tables and creates a SAS dataset as a result:

```
proc sql;
   connect to teradata (user=userid password=password mode=teradata);
   create table mydata as
   select * from connection to teradata (
      select a.customer_id
           , a.customer_name
           , b.last_payment_date
           , b.last_payment_amt
      from base.customers a
      join base.invoices b
      on a.customer_id=b.customer_id
      where b.bill_month = date '2013-07-01'
        and b.paid_flag = 'N'
      );
quit;
```

Notice that everything inside the pair of parentheses is native Teradata SQL and that the join operation itself is running inside the database.

The example code you have shown in your question is **NOT** a complete, working example of a SAS/Teradata program.  To better assist, you need to show the real program, including any library references.  For example, suppose your real program looks like this:

```
proc sql;
   CREATE TABLE subset_data AS
   SELECT bigTable.id,
          SUM(bigTable.value) AS total
   FROM   TDATA.bigTable bigTable
   JOIN   TDATA.subset subset
   ON     subset.id = bigTable.id
   WHERE  bigTable.date BETWEEN a AND b
   GROUP BY bigTable.id
   ;
```

That would indicate a previously assigned LIBNAME statement through which SAS was connecting to Teradata.  The syntax of that WHERE clause would be very relevant to if SAS is even able to pass the complete query to Teradata. (You example doesn't show what "a" and "b" refer to.  It is very possible that the only way SAS can perform the join is to drag both tables back into a local work session and perform the join on your SAS server.

One thing I can strongly suggest is that you try to convince your Teradata administrators to allow you to create "driver" tables in some utility database.  The idea is that you would create a relatively small table inside Teradata containing the ID's you want to extract, then use that table to perform explicit joins.  I'm sure you would need a bit more formal database training to do that (like how to define a proper index and how to "collect statistics"), but with that knowledge and ability, your work will just fly.

I could go on and on but I'll stop here.  I use SAS with Teradata extensively every day against what I'm told is one of the largest Teradata environments on the planet.  I enjoy programming in both.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks so much for the information.  I'm still learning about SAS and Teradata because I am new to both, having done almost everything in R hitting a proprietary database format in my old job.  I will post a more complete example of the code in an edit to my original question.  I'm curious to see what you make of it.  I will also try to figure out that status of the driver tables.  It seems like that would be a good idea, especially the ways I need to query this data.  Again, thank you so much for the advice, I really do appreciate and learn from it.

Comment: Jeff, your updated question shows you really do want to use a pass-through query.  The way you are doing it now guarantees that the entire table must be downloaded from Teradata because you are joining to a SAS dataset.  I suggest you ask a new question since the answers to this one have gotten a little out of scope.  When you do so, see if you can find the original LIBNAME statement that defines `mydb`.

Answer (score 1):

You imply an assumption that the 90k records in your first query are all unique `id`s.  Is that definite?

I ask because the implication from your second query is that they're not unique.
  - One `id` can have multiple values over time, and have different `somevalue`s

If the `id`s are not unique in the first dataset, you need to `GROUP BY id` or use `DISTINCT`, in the first query.

Imagine that the 90k rows consists of 30k unique `id`s, and so have an average of 3 rows per `id`.

And then imagine those 30k unique `id`s actually have 9 records in your time window, including rows where `somevalue <> x`.

You will then get 3x9 records back per `id`.

And as those two numbers grow, the number of records in your second query grows geometrically.

**Alternative Query**

If that's not the problem, an alternative query (which is not ideal, but possible) would be...

```
SELECT
  bigTable.id,
  SUM(bigTable.value) AS total
FROM
  bigTable
WHERE
  bigTable.date BETWEEN a AND b
GROUP BY
  bigTable.id
HAVING
  MAX(CASE WHEN bigTable.somevalue = x THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

Comment: That's a good point, thanks for bringing it up.  The ID's are definitely unique.  The actual subset query is more complicated but the ultimate output is a `DISTINCT` list.

I haven't used a `HAVING` statement before, I will give that a try and see if it helps.

Comment: Just to test things, I added a timestamp to a small subset of the query date range.  Without the join it took 13.57 (0.41 CPU) seconds to return 250k records.

With the join, it took 29.09 (1.12 CPU) seconds to fetch 1800 rows.  How strange.

Comment: Also, running the main query first and then applying the join afterward (subquery) runs in 15.97 seconds.  It's able to calculate ALL of the sums then pare them down faster than paring and then summing.

Comment: @JeffreyKramer - What is the Primary Index on the table?  It feels as though the biggest overhead is Teradata having to shuffle data around the amps.

Comment: I've found that to be common in any SQL flavor - join first, then do groupings later, rather than join+group in one step.  I have no idea why.

Comment: @joe - I've used MySQL, PostgreSQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle, Teradata and Sybase, for near on a decade now.  And yet I've never experienced what you say, even on tables with no index at all.

Answer (score 1):

If ID is unique and a single value, then you can try constructing a format.

Create a dataset that looks like this:

`fmtname, start, label`

where fmtname is the same for all records, a legal format name (begins and ends with a letter, contains alphanumeric or _); start is the ID value; and label is a 1.  Then add one row with the same value for fmtname, a blank start, a label of 0, and another variable, `hlo='o'` (for 'other').   Then import into proc format using the `CNTLIN` option, and you now have a 1/0 value conversion.

Here's a brief example using SASHELP.CLASS.  ID here is name, but it can be numeric or character - whichever is right for your use.

```
data for_fmt;
set sashelp.class;
retain fmtname '$IDF'; *Format name is up to you.  Should have $ if ID is character, no $ if numeric;
start=name; *this would be your ID variable - the look up;
label='1';
output;
if _n_ = 1 then do;
  hlo='o';
  call missing(start);
  label='0';
  output;
end;
run;
proc format cntlin=for_fmt;
quit;
```

Now instead of doing a join, you can do your query 'normally' but with an additional where clause of `and put(id,$IDF.)='1'`.  This won't be optimized with an index or anything, but it may be faster than the join.  (It may also not be faster - depends on how the SQL optimizer is working.)

Comment: Thanks Joe, I see where you are going with this.  The basic idea is to apply a label to the large set and then simply filter off of that label, rather than do a join.  

Unfortunately it's not a single value so I can't really apply it this way.  However, it's an interesting thing to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

If the id is unique you might add a UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX(id) to that table, otherwise it defaults to a Non-unique PI.
Knowing about uniquenes helps the optimizer to produce a better plan.

Without more info like an Explain (just put EXPLAIN in front of the SELECT) it's hard to tell how this can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

One alternate solution is to use SAS procedures.  I don't know what your actual SQL is doing, but if you're just doing frequencies (or something else that can be done in a PROC), you could do:

```
proc sql;
create view blah as select ... (your join);
quit;

proc freq data=blah;
tables id/out=summary(rename=count=total keep=id count);
run;
```

Or any number of other options (PROC MEANS, PROC TABULATE, etc.).  That may be faster than doing the sum in SQL (depending on some details, such as how your data is organized, what you're actually doing, and how much memory you have available).  It has the added benefit that SAS might choose to do this in-database, if you create the view in the database, which might be faster.  (In fact, if you just run the freq off the base table, it's possible that would be even faster, and then join the results to the smaller table).